# Resize a selection to last row in data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that needs to copy the selection from cells `A3:K3` down to the last row of data in column `L`. I have this to get the last cell

```
Dim lastcell As Long
lastcell = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & cell.Count).End(xlUp).cell
```

I would think I have to then offset to the left one, resize the selection to column a and go up to the last filled in row. There might be different ways of doing this maybe some how saving as a variable the last row in the data the selecting the `A3:k3` down to that last row.

Answer (score 0):

This copies columns **A** through **K** rows **3** through **lastcell** to another sheet:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim lastcell As Long
    lastcell = ActiveSheet.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A3:K" & lastcell).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Quite odd this is not working for me for some reason it coipies up to the 31st row as if it thinks that is that last cell, dont see anything particularly wrong in the data that would cause that issue

Comment: Actually im just realizing what your code does, I need to copy a2:k2 from a3:k3 down to the last row in the data (last row in column L)